# Redux doesn't update component after e.stopPropagation()

Tags: reactjs, onclick, redux, stoppropagation

I have a list of Bootstrap list items with each a text and a button. When the user clicks on the item it is selected, when he clicks on the button within an item the item is deleted, and should not be selected ;-) So I use e.stopPropagation() in the Button-onClick. Here is the component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import moment from 'moment';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

import './messagesList.css';

const DATE_FORMAT = 'ddd DD MMMM, H:mm';

export default ({ messages, currentMessage, selectMessage, deleteMessage }) =>
  <ListGroup>
    {messages.map((message, i) => {
      const active = currentMessage === i;
      return (
        <ListGroupItem
          key={message.time_sent}
          active={active}
          onClick={() => selectMessage(i)}
          className={message.read ? '' : 'MessageListRead'}
        >
          <span className="MessageListLabel">From:</span>&nbsp;
          <span>{message.sender}</span>
          <br />
          <span className="MessageListLabel">Subject:</span>&nbsp;
          <span>{message.subject}</span>
          <br />
          <span className="MessageListLabel">Sent:</span>&nbsp;
          <span>{moment.unix(message.time_sent).format(DATE_FORMAT)}</span>

          <Button
            className="MessageListDelete"
            onClick={(e) => {
              deleteMessage(message.id);
              e.stopPropagation();
            }}
          >
            <FontAwesome name="trash" />
          </Button>
        </ListGroupItem>
      );
    })}
  </ListGroup>;
```

And the parent component has:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(4, messages);
  }


  deleteMessage(messageId) {
    const { deleteMessage } = this.props;

    console.log(1, messageId)
    
    deleteMessage(messageId);

    // this.forceUpdate(); solves the problem, only not nice
  }
    
...

        <td className="InboxMessagesList">
          <MessagesList
            messages={messages}
            currentMessage={currentMessage}
            selectMessage={message => this.selectMessage(message)}
            deleteMessage={message => this.deleteMessage(message)}
          />
        </td>
```

The Redux store is correctly updated (item is deleted), but after that the component not updated. When I remove e.stopPropagation() everything works fine.

The Action:

```
export const deleteMessage = messageId => {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log(2, messageId);

    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_MAIL,
      payload: messageId
    });
  };
};
```

The Reducer:

```
case

 DELETE_MAIL:
      const m = messages.find(message => message.id === action.payload),
        index = messages.indexOf(m);

      if (index > -1) messages.splice(index, 1);

      console.log(3, messages);

      return {
        ...state,
        messages
      };
```

Why is the update not triggered?

The console looks like this, after a click on a delete button:

> 4 (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> 1 1002
>
> 2 1002
>
> 3 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: Try to console.log the messages afterwards to actually make sure you are receiving the updated messages.

Comment: @HemersonCarlin I added logs. It seems really not to update.

Comment: And if you log the messages inside `MessagesList` you still got 6 back?

Comment: No, that's 5. Now I added a this.forceUpdate() in the end of the deleteMessage(messageId) function. Then everything works fine. It just doesn't seem to do an update.

Comment: Hmm... that still doesn't solve it all but rather hide the symptom. I'd try to remove the whole react-bootstrap noisy components and try the dumb way by rendering the messages wrapped in a `<div>` only. Of course, you still need the click handler to dispatch your delete action.